# Adding item to a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Hi i am trying to create a linked list to test a function with it but it gives me an error and I can't find out what the problem is with my code. When I fist enter the number, the cmd window stops working after I hit enter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct llist *link;
typedef struct llist{
    int id;
    link next, pre;
} list;

list *location;
int id_input, size = 0;

int search (int id);
int add(void);
int read(void);
int delete(short id);

int main();

int read(void)
{
    printf("enter input id: ");
    scanf("%d", id_input);
    getchar();
}

int add(void)
{
    list *new_item;
    new_item = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    printf("%p", new_item);
    switch(size==0){
        case 1:{
            location = new_item;
            location->pre = NULL;
            location->next = NULL;
            break;
        }
        case 0:{
            location->next=new_item;
            new_item->pre=location;
            new_item->next=NULL;
            location=new_item;
            break;
        }
    }
    location->id = id_input;
}

int main()
{
    int x,i;
    printf("start to append the list\n");
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        read();
        add();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: add an `fflush` after the `printf` in `read()`

Comment: What do you mean by "it give error"?  That contradicts "the cmd window stop working".

Comment: sorry for my use of word since I'm not native english speaker. I means the window took time and can't give any result and it stop working. It is like doing infinite loop without stop condition. That's what I mean

Answer (score 2):

```
int read(void)
{
    printf("enter input id: ");
    scanf("%d", &id_input); //you are missing & here
    getchar();
}
```